# Importing Google coordinates to QGIS but can't select X/Y field, because coordinates are shown in one row

Tags: qgis, csv, mac

I am new to QGIS. I am attempting to import CSV file with x/y coordinates into QGIS. When I add CSV file to delimited text layer all coordinates are shown in one row, so I can't select which one is X or Y. It's the same when I import txt.file.[image: csv file imported]

I am working on Mac so maybe that's a problem. I also saved a file as Windows formatted file CSV. This has not helped ethier. The X and Y coordinates are in columns, but when I have to select X or Y field the columns are merged together as X;Y.
[image: imported Windows formatted file CSV]

Comment: How about selecting semicolon?

Answer (score 5):

The separator in your CSV is a semicolon. In 'File format' instead of selecting 'Tab' select 'Semicolon' (highlighted) and the coordinates will appear in separated columns.

[image]